# How to minimize spacing b/w subfigure and label less than 1cm?

Tags: subfig, sidesubfloat

[image]

I want to reduce spacing b/w labels and figures. But after the label to be very close to subfigues but with the following setting I can't reduce it less than 1cm.

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,amsmath,amssymb,]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
%\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\setlength{\labelsep}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!htb]

    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig1.png}}

    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig2.png}}

    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig3.png}}
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig4.png}}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: never use `\begin{figure*}[!htb]`  the `figure*` environment does not support `h` and (by default) does not support `b` so this is equivalent to `\begin{figure*}[!t]` so its main effect is to prevent `p` ie prevent the float being placed on a float page, so makes it highly likely that the figure drifts to the end of the document.

Comment: please always post _complete_ small documents that show the problem (you can use `example-image` as the image so that everyone can run the document). It is impossible to guess the issue or a fix just given a fragment like this.

Comment: I have added my result. As it can seen that the spacing b/w (a) and fig is too large. I want to minimize this spacing ,i used \labelsep but it is more effective for increasing this spacing not for reducing it.

Comment: Do you really need `floatrow` here? In any case, as I say, please post a test document so people can test answers. `\labelsep` is normally associated with list environments does it do anything here?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to add text document. I can only attach a figure here. if \labelspe{3cm} it increases disdtace b/w (a) and its figure. I see floatrow package using sidesubfloat  so I also used it. But I'm not sure what wil be its effect

Comment: You can not attach a document, but you should edit the code fragment that you have in the question to be a complete document, look at almost all the posts on this site for examples of what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Well, you nearly got it, but there are some issues in your code resulting in your not wished layout.

Please see the following issues:

1. Do not write blank lines inside your figure as you did. please see the following MWE for corrected code ...
2. Comment `\setlength{\labelsep}{1cm}` to get the label near to the image.
3. Uncomment `%\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}` to get the label at the uper left corner of the image as wished ...
4. Use `\hfil` to get the space between first and second image in a row greater ...
5. Please see that I used `width=0.45\linewidth` for the width of the images ...

Please see the following corrected MWE (package `showframe` only used to isualize the typing area and margins):

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}

\usepackage{showframe} % <==============================================
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
%\setlength{\labelsep}{1cm}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \sidesubfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\hfil
  \sidesubfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

  \sidesubfloat[c]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}}\hfil
  \sidesubfloat[d]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting figure]